# Rails: Using Bootstrap Input Style to Replace the built-in form_for method in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to use [Bootstrap forms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) in Rails. But after inspecting the _form partial created by my post scaffold, I'm not quite sure how I can edit the variables with regular input methods.

**For example, this is the built-in form code:**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :content %><br />
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
 <div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**I want to use the form code below:**

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Start posting</legend>
<label>Name</label>
 <input class="span10" type="text" placeholder="Name: ">
<label>Content</label>
 <input class="span10" type="text" placeholder="Content: ">
<textarea rows="10"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**Question: How do I use Bootstrap version of form code?**

I tried something like..

```
<input class="span10" type="text" name="@post.name" placeholder="Type in name: ">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I thought the Bootstrap submit button is not pointing at the right direction, so I tried the following as well:

```
<input class="span10" type="text" name="@post.name" placeholder="Type in name: ">
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Could someone please help me with this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are u using twitter- bootstrap gem ?

Comment: No. Is it recommended to do so? I just downloaded the compiled version of Bootstrap and put them into my assets folder. So far I haven't found any inconvenience. If I use the gem, how is it different for me to use the above form for my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it manually, you should add twitter-bootstrap-rails gem to your app. Se here for instructions and documentation: [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

That will do the trick!

Comment: After I install the gem, does the form_for method automatically use the bootstrap version of input style? I'd appreciate if I could learn the manual way as well..

Comment: There is no point in doing it manually for a rails project. Check documentation and the screencasts in the link I posted you.